# Writing the plane as {(x,y,z): x+y+z=0}

Tags: terminology, plane-geometry

One can coordinatize the plane by choosing three axes at 120 degree angles and representing points by triples $(x,y,z)$ with $x+y+z=0$. Is there an accepted name for this kind of coordinate system? (It corresponds to the standard irreducible representation of $S_3$, but it is not the "standard" way to coordinatize the plane!)

Comment: I think "barycentric coordinates" is one term that is used for essentially this system, especially in e.g. computer graphics. See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Barycentric_coordinates_on_triangles.

Comment: Buckminster Fuller spent a long time promoting an approach to geometry based on this idea under the name [synergetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synergetics_(Fuller)). \\ By the way, speaking of names, I think the standard irreducible representation of $S_3$ is more commonly called its reflection representation.

Comment: @LSpice: "Standard representation" is also a standard name- see https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Standard_representation or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_symmetric_group.

Comment: @Sam Hopkins: I agree that the barycentric coordinates representation is similar, but it's not exactly the same thing. (Note that the Wikipedia article says "Every point has barycentric coordinates, and their sum is not zero.")

Comment: @JamesPropp: The only difference is $x+y+z=1$ versus $x+y+z=0$ but that just amounts to subtracting $\frac{1}{3}$ from each coordinate.

Comment: Alternatively, it really is barycentric coordinates with respect to the equilateral triangle which has vertices $(1,-1,0)$, $(0,1,-1)$, and $(-1,0,1)$.

Comment: @Sam Hopkins: I like your last point. I'm going to call it the "zero-sum barycentric coordinate representation" unless someone can suggest a term that's already in the literature.